# Geometry Shader instancing after tessellation

Tags: vulkan

In a Geometry Shader, I need the index of the current triangle within the patch being currently tessellated by the Tessellation Control Shader.

Since `gl_PrimitiveIDIn` is called per-primitive, and reading [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader_Instancing) :"*The GS can also be instanced ... This causes the GS to execute multiple times for the same input primitive. Each invocation of the GS for a particular input primitive will get a different gl_InvocationID value.*"

knowing that a patch is always being tessellated into n triangles, I am finding the index of the current triangle within a patch as `index = gl_PrimitiveIDIn * n + gl_InvocationID;`

It works. But I am not comfortable beacuse the same link also states:

"*To use instancing, there must be an input layout qualifier:
layout(invocations = num_instances​) in;*"

which is **not** my case, because I have no layout qualifier like this. Yet the Geometry Shader **is** invoked multiple times on the same primitive in case of a tessellation, at least in my case, and `gl_InvocationID` **is** updated accordingly.

Can I safely assume that a Geometry Shader following a Tessellation Control Shader will be instanced multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I safely assume that a Geometry Shader following a Tessellation Control Shader will be instanced multiple times?

No. Indeed, you can assume that GS instancing will only be used if you *ask for it*. Because that's how the feature *works*.

It isn't clear why `index = gl_PrimitiveIDIn * n + gl_InvocationID;` "works," but it certainly does not make `index` produce a per-tessellated-primitive index. Maybe `n` is 1 for some reason. `gl_InvocationID` will be zero.

[GS instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Instancing) reuses the same input primitive for all of the instances. The only difference between invocations of the GS for instances will be the value of `gl_InvocationID`. This *includes* the input primitive; they will all be the same vertices for all instances. GS instancing *does not care* about tessellation.

You seem to want a counter that starts at zero at the beginning of the tessellation of a patch, and increments for each primitive output by the tessellation primitive generator. That is not actually possible to compute.

The GS lacks any knowledge of which primitives come from which patches. [`gl_PrimitiveIDIn` counts all primitives within the draw call](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Inputs), so if you're rendering more than one patch, it has no idea how to handle that. If all of the patches are being subdivided into the *same* number of primitives, then you could do `gl_PrimitiveIDIn % n` to get the index within a patch. But that's about it.

The only code that might be able to produce such a counter is the TES. However, even if it could, it lacks the ability to output per-primitive information. It can output per-vertex information, but it cannot know which vertices are the [provoking vertex for a particular output primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Provoking_vertex) (indeed, a provoking vertex might be shared between multiple primitives). So it cannot deliver an index value.

Comment: thanks for your -as always- comprehensive explanation. I knew I was getting false positive results.

Comment: just an update: it seems like gl_PrimitiveIDIn is updated per input-primitive, regardless of the TEC (Tessellation Control Shader) generated output. i.e. if a triangle is tessellated by the TEC into 24 triangles, when each of the 24 tris reach the Geometry Shader, each GS invocation will have the same gl_PrimitiveIDIn. In other words, if 10 tris are subdivided into a total of 200 tris, all the 200 GS invocation will have a gl_PrimitiveIDIn ranging from 0 to 9. IDK if this is what you meant, I just wanted to include this for clarity.

Comment: @user815129: The specification is kind of unclear on this. I'll take a look at what Vulkan says.

Comment: @user815129: The Vulkan spec says that it is "the number of primitives presented as input to the [geometry] shader since the current set of rendering primitives was started." And the Vulkan GLSL->SPIR-V mapping specification (as well as the OpenGL equivalent) says that `PrimitiveID` ought to be equivalent to `gl_PrimitivieIDIn`. Which suggests that you're seeing a bug.

Comment: this is unfortunate, my whole GS relies on a unique index. At the time being I am solving this with an atomic counter, just to be on the safe side. I have a feeling that this time the Vulkan spec wording might not be 100% accurate, but no proofs for that, I might very well be seeing a(nother) bug.